puts method not working on cucumber test report
I want to print the text I copied from the web page on to the cucumber html test report step but I can only see it in the console does anyone know how to resolve this?
Then ('on step 5 should show price') do 
puts @browser.element(:class =>'price').text.strip 
end 

on my execute window batch command I'm using -
--no source --colour --format pretty --format json --out=
Thanks

"puts method not working" – is output from a cucumber test supposed to be included in the report?
